# How do I store Argon2 passwords in my database?

Tags: hash, passwords

I'm trying to store user passwords in my DB using Argon2 algorithm.

This is what I obtain by using it:

```
$echo -n "password" | argon2 "smallsalt" -id -t 4 -m 18 -p 4
Type:           Argon2id
Iterations:     4
Memory:         262144 KiB
Parallelism:    4
Hash:           cb4447d91dd62b085a555e13ebcc6f04f4c666388606b2c401ddf803055f54ac
Encoded:        $argon2id$v=19$m=262144,t=4,p=4$c21hbGxzYWx0$y0RH2R3WKwhaVV4T68xvBPTGZjiGBrLEAd34AwVfVKw
1.486 seconds
Verification ok
```

In this case, **what** should I store in the DB?

- The "encoded" value as shown above?
- The "hash" value as shown above?
- Neither, but another solution?

Please, could you help me? I'm a newbie with this and I'm a little bit lost.

Comment: This question is not related to directly Cryptography rather than its impelmentation so this belongs to SO. In practice, keep it all together in one column.

Comment: The main question is if I should store the encoded or hash filed in DB

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*I'm a bit late to the party, but I disagree with the previous answers.*
You should store the field: *Encoded* 
The *$argon2id$....* value.

(At least if you are using normal Argon2 libraries having the `verify()` function.
It does not look like the [man-page for argon2](http://manpages.org/argon2) command does this, however.

Only if you are stuck with the command line, you should consider storing each field individually.)

**The $argon2id$ encoded hash**
The argon2 encoded hash follows the same as its older cousin [bcrypt's syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

The encoded hash includes all you ever need to verify the hash when the user logs in.

It is most likely more future proof. When a newer and better argon2 comes along: You can upgrade your one column hashed passwords. Just like you could detect bcrypt's $2a$-hashes, and re-hash them as $argon2id$-hashes, next time the user logs in. (If you were moving from bcrypt to agron2.)

**TL;DR** 
Store the $-encoded value `encoded_hash` in your database.
Use `argon2.verify(password, encoded_hash)` to verify that the password is correct.

Don't bother about all the values inside the hash. Let the library do that for you. :)

Comment: Also: Remember to run argon2.verify(...) even if the user does not exist.  This way, both existing users and non-existing users will spend the same amout of time, before the reply is sent...

Answer (score 4):

Neither. Save following as a single value:

- algorithm ID (e.g. argon2id)
- salt
- number of iterations (4)
- memory usage factor (18)
- parallelism (4)

The output of the field "encoded" is misleading because you cannot use it *as is* for password check (i.e. for hash generation), e.g. m=262144 where as for password check you need the original factor m=18.

Are you going to launch an OS process each time you check password? I would discourage you from doing this. I'd suggest you use a library (C++, Java, ...). They produce a string that contains all these data concatenated and separated with "$".

Comment: I agree that the argon2 command line tools is using `m` differently. But m=18 and m=262144, is actually the same. Just written differently.  The command line reads m=18 as 2<sup>18</sup>, which is 262144. (I agree with the linux tool, but the argon2 spec is using number of actual kilobytes in their $-encoded string.)

Comment: I cam across the same thing...  For command line you need to use the -k option for the m= value from in the encoded string.   Arrrgghhhh....
Even the 'version' number (-v) does not correspond to the 'v=' in the hash!
Why did they not allow the command line to decode the encoded hash itself!  It knows what the line should look like!    A option to say if it needs 're-encoding' would also be good!
Can't way for "openssl" to do its own implementation!

Comment: @anthony: What you mean by *"Why did they not allow the command line"*? Who you mean by *"they"*? Algorithm Argon2 developed by the authors has **nothing to do** with representation and storing of parameters. You seem to mix these very different things. How do you store parameters, is up to you. You can use any parameter names you want, any delimiters, you can use even separate entry in database for every parameter. This is what the question is about. I think you have not understood the question and have not understood what is related to algorithm and what is independent on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the `type`, `iterations`, `memory`, `parallelism`, `hash`, `salt` and corresponding user id into separate columns and leave the encoded bit out, because it's just all the attributes joined together. If they're in separate columns then you can reference the attributes more easily than having to split and index the encoded string.

The other option is to just store the encoded string in 1 column, but as I said its more tedious to look at certain attributes, as you'd have to split the encoded string and then index it.

Comment: The API already gives you encode and decode, why do you advice separate columns?

Comment: Because if you wanted to check the parameters for someones hashed password to check the password when entered on a form for example, rather than having to index the encoded string to find each individual attribute, it can be referenced just by looking at the columns corresponding to the user id.

Comment: I see the complete string as "encoded" field. So what is "hash" field used for?

Comment: The hash field is just the digest of the hash algorithm, the encoded contains all the hash parameters joined up into one large string

Comment: No well-engineered library should be requiring the programmer to parse the individual fields. The implementation should be abstracting this foot-gun away from the developer. If your Argon2 library is making you do this, or you're rolling your own, something is wrong.

Comment: Something is wrong, @Royce Williams.  One should use `argon2.verify(password, encoded_hash)` for checking the users' passwords.

Comment: Yep, agreed 100%

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and read this post while gathering some information. Now after some days and thoughts about all this, I'll personally take a different route than the accepted answer and therefore slightly disagree with it. I thought I would share my perspective so that it might help others as well.

I suppose it will depend on everyone's context. I don't think there is a one size fits all answer here. I'm sure there are situations where it is perfectly valid and even better/simpler to store the encoded string ($argon2...).

However, I would argue that depending on the context, storing the encoded string doesn't seem to be the right approach.

First of all, it makes the hashing method very obvious. It is probably not that important but for some reasons it makes me a bit more comfortable not having it ^^. But, more importantly, it means that implementation details are stored in your persistence layer (db or else). At the time of writing, argon2id is the recommended hashing mechanism by OWASP but these things can change (eventually do change...). Some day, it might be considered unsecure, or another function will be considered more secure.

As a result, I would suggest this more function "agnostic" starting point:

- The hash (for argon2 -> the hex string)
- The salt
- The last_modified date
- A string with hashing parameters (for argon2, you could put the parameters here in the form of your choosing)

The last_modified allows to know if the hash needs updating or not and the parameters allows to support the verification and update of "old" hashes.

Of course this means that you have to work a bit more in the code and can't simply use every libraries shortcuts straight away. But, I would say that this increased complexity offer more flexibility in other circumstances (like moving away from a given hashing function). As always there are no free lunch.

That's why I suppose it depends on your context and why personally I wouldn't go with the accepted answer in my situation.

PS: I'm no cryptography expert nor some devsecop guru. So feel free to contradict, enrich, agree or disagree. I just like to keep my implementation details contained ;)

Comment: The security lies in the argon parameters, not in hiding the use of argon2. (You could find out that argon was used from the length of the hash together with the input parameters, anyway.)

Storing the standardized $ hash string, may make it easier to upgrade, as everything is contained in one single field. Even if new algoritm may add new buts. The bcrypt uses $2a$, scrypt uses $s0$, and argon uses $argon2[i|d]$. All for a reason. Why not follow the standard way, when it makes things simpler for you? : )